# How to provide password in a secure way to LDAP seed?

Tags: openldap, pxe, preseed

I am pxe installing Ubuntu over a network, unattended. I want Ldap installed as well, but I need to provide the ldap db root password in the seed:

```
ldap-auth-config  ldap-auth-config/rootbindpw   password
```

How can I keep this secure? I don't want to provide the plain text password on this line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, it's not possible.

You can preseed a pre-encrypted password for the root and the first user accounts.  You can even do it with the grub password (and a few others too).  e.g.

```
d-i passwd/root-password-crypted password [MD5 hash]
d-i passwd/user-password-crypted password [MD5 hash]
d-i grub-installer/password-crypted password [MD5 hash]
```

but that won't work for `ldap-auth-config/rootbindpw` because you need the **unencrypted** password in your LDAP config to connect to the LDAP server.

The only thing I can suggest is to use a dummy password in the pre-seed, and script an ssh connection **TO** the freshly-built new machine, to set the real rootbindpw.  This has to be a 'push' operation rather than a 'pull' otherwise you're just shifting the problem from preseed to somewhere else.